# Stopping Continues Testing recompilation stealing cursor in Visual Studios 2017 and Resharper

Tags: c#, output, resharper, continuous-testing

I have just started out on my journey to learn TDD with C# and to help me I have started using Reshaper 2017.1.3 Continues Testing tool to re-run all my tests that are affected by my modifications upon saving. I was hoping this would be a seamless experience with no interruptions to development but every time the projects need to be recompiled the cursor is stolen from the editor and placed inside the Output Pane which leads to a halt in development.

Is there any way to stop this behaviour without having to sacrifice the convince of the Continues Testing tool?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might be Visual Studio behaviour - try unchecking the "Show output window when build starts" option in Tools → Options → Projects and Solutions → General.

If this doesn't help, please report an issue: [youtrack.jetbrains.com](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com)

Comment: There is no such option in VS 2017 15.9.5

Answer (score 0):

In my case I wanted to keep the focus in the editor after running my program and this solution is still available in 2021 for Visual Studio 2019.

Here is a screenshot for Visual Studio in French:

[image]